# How to improve SEO while using MVC with AJAX

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, seo

I am developing a site using asp.net MVC. I have used AJAX for paging,sorting dropdown fillup,showing different content on link click etc. I came to know that AJAX call is always against SEO and SEO is most important for my site. 
Please suggest me ways to improve SEO of my site without removing AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have been using progressive enhancement from the start. Your site should work without JavaScript/Ajax being enabled. This way all users, including search engines, can get to your content. Then you should *enhance* your users' experience by adding JavaScript and Ajax to provide a better experience.

At this point you don't have a lot of options. You'll need to go back and make that content available without JavaScript. You can also use [Google's crawlable Ajax standard](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html), too, but that only works for Google and for a slightly more amount of work you can make every search engine, and every user, able to reach your content by not making JavaScript required to use your website.